# Maven sonar:sonar failing using the latest plugin version

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonar from within Maven v3.3.3, using the v2.7.1 of the org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin, but I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project mio-tbc: org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.MavenScmConfiguration has unsatisfied dependency 'class org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject' for constructor 'public org.sonar.plugins.scmstats.MavenScmConfiguration(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@e97f51c:205<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@377e90b0:211<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@64921450:36<| -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the Scm Stats Plugin. I suggest you to remove it (it is not compatible with SonarQube 5.2).